# Homology/Fundamental Group question

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am having trouble with this question.  I appreciate any help.

The suspension of a space $Y$ is the quotient space of $Y \times  I$ obtained
by identifying $Y \times \{0\}$ to a point and separately identifying $Y \times \{1\}$
to a point.
Let X denote the suspension of $\mathbb{R}P^
2$.

(a) Compute $\pi_1(X)$.

(b) Compute all the homology groups of X.

Comment: Indeed... What have you tried? This is a standard exercise which iss either stated as such in every book or actually done in detail, usually right after computing the homology of spheres. It would be ideal if you told us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $p_0$ and $p_1$ denote the two "end points". Check that if you remove either of these points, the resulting space is contractible. Use this in conjunction with Van Kampen/Mayer-Vietoris.